# Source of statement that unqualified Jihad means Jihad by the sword?

Tags: source-identification, jihad

I was reading an article in a magazine which quoted a rule from Ibn Hajar Al-Asqalani, roughly translated it says:

> In the Kitab and Sunnah whenever the word jihad is used without a
>   restriction added on to it, such as with wealth or with life, the
>   salaf are fully in agreement that it means war with the sword.

I would like a reference (original book etc. by Ibn Hajar) for this if someone can find it.

Comment: By "reference" are you referring to an original source where Ibn Hajar al-Asqalani said that, or are you referring to the original evidences Ibn Hajar al-Asqalani based that opinion on?

Comment: Interesting question: I found this quote on many Islamic sites, but with no source or reference.